# LARAVEL: My data is not stored in my database when posted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm building a scrape website for my laravel project.
On my admin-page I want to be able to store multiple sorts of data like 'urls' and on another form 'categories'. So those are multiple forms on one page (not sure if that is possible..).
I wrote my function so that when my data is stored, it will refresh the page. So that worked but when I went checking in my database to verify, nothing was there and I've been setting up create functions in laravel but this one is so difficult to know where it goes wrong.
This is my code:

My admin page:

```
<body class="relative min-h-screen">
    @include('partials.header')
   <main class="">
       <div class="text-center m-auto text-2xl p-4 w-fit border-b">
           <h2>Welkom <strong>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</strong></h2>
       </div>
       <div class="gap-10 m-auto xl:w-3/5">
            <div class="mt-8 min-h-screen">
                <h3 class="bg-gray-100 p-4"><strong>Scrapes</strong></h3>
                <div class="">
                    <div class="p-4 m-auto">
                        <form action="{{ route('admin', Auth()->user()) }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="flex wrap flex-row items-center justify-left my-4">
                                <label for="shop" class="w-2/12">Webshop:</label>
                                <select name="shop" id="shop" class="w-4/12 h-fit p-2 focus:outline-sky-500 rounded bg-slate-100">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex wrap flex-row items-center justify-left">
                                <label for="url" class="w-2/12">
                                   Voeg een url toe:
                                </label>
                                <input type="url" required class="w-7/12 h-fit p-2 focus:outline-sky-500 rounded bg-slate-100" name="url" id="url" placeholder="bvb.: http://dreambaby.com/speelgoed">
                                <button class="w-fit bg-green-400 h-fit p-2 rounded hover:bg-green-600 hover:text-white mx-2" type="submit">Voeg link toe</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
    
                        <form action="{{ route('admin', Auth()->user()) }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PUT')
                            <div class="flex wrap flex-row items-center justify-left">
                                <label for="url" class="w-2/12">
                                   Voeg een categorie toe:
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" required class="w-7/12 h-fit p-2 focus:outline-sky-500 rounded bg-slate-100" name="title" id="cat" placeholder="bvb.: Eten en Drinken">
                                <button class="w-fit bg-green-400 h-fit p-2 rounded hover:bg-green-600 hover:text-white mx-2" type="submit">toevoegen</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-8 p-4">
                        <p>Overzicht links:</p>
                        <ul>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </main>
   @include('partials.footer')
</body>
```

My Controller:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function showAdmin($id)
    {
        return view('admin');
    }

    public function storeCat(Request $request)
    {
        $cat = Category::create([
            'title' => $request->input('title')
        ]);
        echo('Tis gelukt');
        return view('admin');
    }

    public function updateCat(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $cat = Category::where('id', $id)
            ->update([
            'title' => $request->input('title')
        ]);
        return back();
    }

    public function destroyCat(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $cat = Category::find($id)->first();
        $cat->delete();
        return back();
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "categories";

    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

My migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My Routes:

```
    Route::get('/admin/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'showAdmin'])
        ->name('admin');

    Route::post('/admin/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'storeCat']);
        
    Route::put('/admin/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'updateCat']); 
    
    Route::delete('/admin/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'destroyCat']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found why it was not working. I just had to remove method('PUT')
But I have no clue what to do when I actually want to edit my categories..